# Run any user apps in safemode?

Tags: applications, troubleshooting, safe-mode

### Some Background

My Note 2 has strange slow down after hours of use. After hours of usage `system_server` and maybe `kworker` use a lot of CPU, mostly during apps open and switch, it lags badly. I also have around 200 user apps installed, and mostly greenified, so I expected that my device shouldn't be slowed down like this even with a lot of apps installed. I used to experience `system_server` and `kworker` using a lot of CPU on Tab 7.7, but less than 30 user apps installed. Even safe mode, changing ROMs doesn't fix the problem; finally wiping both `/data` and internal SD fixed the problem. It is now fast.

So I would like to try running various user apps on safe mode, to see if it still slow down after hours of usage. Or I have to wipe both `/data` and internal SD to fix the slow-down problem like I did in Tab 7.7. I have a lot of data and apps in the internal SD, free space is 1.5 gb/10 gb. I feel lazy to backup and restore (it's a lot of data) and try the fix of wiping data, so I would like to try running a lot of user app in safe mode first. There are some exploits in TouchWiz ROM which allow that:

I'm using [this 4.4.2 firmware](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2504016). On this firmware, I can do it partially. By adding apps to lock-screen shortcut. Those apps can be opened in safe mode. In DN3 Rom before Kitkat update, user apps added to Samsung Note 3 Touchwiz Launcher home screen can also be opened, but not anymore in Kitkat update.

When I installed custom ROMs on Note 2, I never wiped internal SD, I wiped only `/data` partition, an this probably is the cause of lagginess in Tab 7.7.

### My question

So is there any more ways to open user apps in safemode?

Comment: What good shall that do? The purpose of safe-mode is exactly that *no* user apps are opened. It's not a mode you should permanently operate in, but rather intended to be able to remove troublemakers etc. So what you're asking for would rather contradict its definition. What are you trying to achieve? Can you give some background why this should be needed?

Comment: Sorry, it is not kworker on Note 2, it is mmcqd/0.

Comment: Those facts should be part of the question itself – you can [edit] it anytime (I did that for you just now, so you might wish to delete the comments I've integrated). // And as nice as the idea might sound, that's not what safe-mode is for. You should rather 1) make a Nandroid-backup, then 2) completely reset your device, and 3) start over with parts of the apps to find out which one is the culprit.

Comment: as for a reason: my phone is in a boot loop and can only start up successfully in safe mode. yet, i want to make backups and stuff like that, so i'd like to selectively start some apps before i wipe the whole thing.